# NPM Global Install Location on OSX

Tags: macos, node.js, path, installation, npm

On OSX should NPM install global packages to:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

or

```
/usr/local/share/npm
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The global packages get installed to:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

and man pages get installed at (if supplied):

```
/usr/local/share/npm
```

see [this](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders#global-installation) for more information.

Comment: seems that they are now in `/opt/local/lib/node_modules`

Comment: @Motla: How did you install it?

Comment: with the .pkg (LTS v12.16.2)

Comment: @Molta: Thanks for the info, I'll update my answer; can you confirm manual pages are installed in `/opt/local/share/npm`?

Answer (score 9):

The directory will differ depending on whether or not you're using nvm or some other node version manager, and possibly also based on versions of version manager and versions of OSX. Due to the variability here, it may be better to run `npm root -g` which will specify the directory npm is using to store your global modules.